# Is there a plot of the proportion of unanswered questions over time?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

Number of questions: [18,944,038](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/).  Number of unanswered questions: [5,620,789](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered).  The proportion of unanswered questions is currently `5620789 / 18944038 = 26.79%`.

**Question**: Is there a plot of the proportion of unanswered questions over time?

I didn't find a Data Explorer query: [`proportion unanswered`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=proportion%20unanswered) and [`number unanswered`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=number%20unanswered).

Answer (score 16):

I found some [old queries and historical data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noZxp.png) that show the percentage of questions that have any answers and upvoted answers here. On that basis I created some more queries that look at interesting properties of question and answers over time:

- Questions states: [absolute numbers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1197893/question-states-over-time-absolute#graph), [percent](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1197858/question-states-over-time-percent#graph)
- Answer states: [absolute numbers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1197896/answer-states-over-time-absolute#graph), [percent](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1197862/answer-states-over-time-percent#graph)

The results for questions look like this:

[image: Absolute numbers for question states]

In percent:

[image: Relative numbers for question states]

This includes deleted posts (to exclude those, replace all occurrences of `PostsWithDeleted` with `Posts` in the queries).

The numbers of answers have been going down basically since the beginning.

Comment: Now I'd like to see that juxtaposed with question volume and average question score…

Comment: @deceze can you specify "question volume" - the size of the question body? The amount of questions being posted at a regular interval? HOW LOUD THE QUESTION (or the title) IS? Because I can genuinely see each of these being an interesting metric.

Comment: *smirk* Just simply *how many* questions were posted in the same time interval. Obvious hypothesis: more questions, with average worse quality, leading to a decline in answered percentage. Probably also largely due to many of them being plainly unanswerable.

Comment: IF YOU CAN FACTOR LOUDNESS IN AS WELL, THAT'D OBVIOUSLY BE AWESOME TOO.

Comment: @deceze the hypothesis is sound. I can also see a link between the size of the body of the question and quality. A "I want to do X. How?" is also common. There are short and *good* questions but overall they tend to still be more than just a line or two of text. And THE LOUD TITLES tend to also be linked with low quality posts. I tend to edit those on sight to change the all caps to proper sentence case, so the title doesn't hurt my eyes. The actual posts are still not very good.

Comment: Sorry, looking at that data again, it already contains the volume, my bad. And it seems there's no inverse correlation between volume and answered percentage. So, now *quality* would be the interesting metric to compare it to.

Comment: @deceze [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76961/question-quality-by-quarter) is a query showing upvoted/downvoted question percentages. The [question where I found this query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143113) and an one of it's [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143137/56338) also have some more interesting queries and historical data for comparison.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed seem to correlate sinking quality with decline in answers. So, volume isn't the issue, sheer unanswerability is.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong. Is this implying that the total number of questions on SO has *decreased*, since 2014? How can that be?

Comment: @code11 The graph show the number of question with each point being a month (if I read the query properly), so it looks like February 2017 did the all time record of questions per month :)

Comment: Looking at this in 2023, the gap between total questions and questions with answers is constantly increasing. Is this concerning for a community?